# Adding a function to display an image based on a URL that changes based on a cell in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hopefully the title isn't confusing.

I'm making a spreadsheet and I want column B to look at the corresponding cell in column A and change the image URL based on that.

For example, something like

```
=IMAGE("http://www.website.com/pics/"(A2)".png")
```

It's been throwing an error, probably because it's expecting a full image URL. Is there a good way to do this that I can just copy it to every cell in a column and it'll look at the right cell and display the correct image?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up opening a second tab on the sheet and putting the first part of the url in a cell

```
http://www.website.com/pics/
```

then I put the last part in another cell

```
.png
```

then copied the links to those cells and went back to the original tab of the sheet I was working on and made a JOIN command using those links.

```
=IMAGE(JOIN("",'Your sheet name here'!$B$1,A11,'Your sheet name here'!$B$3))
```

I had to add the $ in manually so it doesn’t change if you past it elsewhere, change A11 to whatever cell you want to reference.